# Issue with dynamic SQL to get JSON properties as columns when JSON is NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, open-json

I am trying to select JSON properties as column. The properties that needs to be selected are stored in some other table

```
CREATE TABLE [Templates](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Template] [nvarchar](max)
)

INSERT INTO Templates(ID,Template)
VALUES
(1,'{"FirstName":"foo"}'),
(2,'{"FirstName":"joe","LastName":"dow"}'),
(3,'{"LastName":"smith","Address":"1234 Test Drive"}'),
(4,NULL)


Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

--For brevity purpose i am hardcoding these property names. In reality column names will come from another table
DECLARE @properties NVARCHAR(max) = '[Address],[FirstName],[LastName]'

Set @SQL  = '
Select '+ @properties +'
 From  (
        Select T.ID
              ,j.[Key]
              ,j.[Value]
         From  Templates T
         Cross Apply OpenJSON(T.Template) AS j
       ) src
Pivot ( max(value) for [Key] in ('+ @properties +') ) pvt 
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/695292/8)

The code above is mostly working except for the Last row where `Template` is NULL. (ID = 4)
Expected: The query should return 4 rows and for the last row, all columns should be null except ID.

Comment: Change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CROSS APPLY` requires rows to be returned, however, `Cross Apply OpenJSON(NULL) AS j` returns no rows. Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
' ...
OUTER APPLY OpenJSON(T.Template) AS j
...'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Note I also use `sp_executesql` as you can't parametrise `EXEC (@SQL)`

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=acae471945abd19ab864e0dd0d65da2f)